# How to clone select options without cloning the select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a select:

```
<select id="mySelect">
 <option value="1">First</option>
 <option value="2">Second</option>
 <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

I would like to clone all the options without having to clone the select. Is this possible? Cloning the select is not possible in my situation.

I thought of doing something like this:

```
$('#mySelect').html().clone();
```

but that did not work.

Update:

I have a select that will change over time. I have a second select in a modal. When the modal is called, I need to update the modal's select with the same options as the first modal. Both selects have different attributes, thus I can't clone the select.

Comment: Have you tried `PHP`? Please be more specific.

Comment: Not an option either. This has to be done on the client.

Comment: @Krii Where did you get `PHP` from? I see no mention of it in the post or the tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most straightforward way to copy the options from your primary select to the secondary select is to use `html()` as follows:

```
var options = $('#mySelect').html();
$('#mySelect2').html(options);
```

Or in one line:

```
$('#mySelect2').html($('#mySelect').html());
```

If you want to manipulate the options before copying to the other select, then you could use `clone()` to get an array of the individual select options as jQuery objects and alter the array before copying the entires to the other select.  However, based on your updated requirement of simply copying the options from one select to another, using clone would definitely be overkill. But this is how you would do it:

```
var optionsArr = $('#mySelect option').clone();
console.log(optionsArr); // See the contents
// Manipulate and populate other select as needed
```

Comment: So I won't need a clone()? What is the difference between .cone() and .html() ?

Comment: clone() makes a 'deep copy' of the jQuery object(s), and html() returns the HTML contents of the jQuery object.  clone() has its place when you want to do things like duplicate DOM elements.  Whether you need clone() or html() depends significantly on what you want to do with the select options.

Comment: Now that I've read your update indicating you simply want to copy the options from one select to another, you'll want to use the html() option.  You are simply copying a string; no need to bring clone() into this.

Comment: Very well. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot

```
$('#mySelect option').clone()
```

Comment: Worked fine for me.  It returns a jQuery array rather than a string with the innerHTML, but all option elements are there (using jQuery 1.11.1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clone()` to generate the clones then `appendTo` to append the new option elements to a new select and then use `appendTo` again to append the new select to the body. This little trick works like a charm:

```
$('#'+original_id+' option').clone().appendTo($('<select id="'+new_id+'">').appendTo('body'));
```

Considering that you are appending the copy elements to the end of the body.

This is a demo that shows how you can generate the copies:

https://jsfiddle.net/m323ww1p/